# How to Create the event before cell change with cancel in Excel. For the active cell

Tags: excel, vba, events

vba -excel

Is there a better solution for this event that I described?

```
Dim bitExit As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If bitExit Then
Application.Undo
bitExit = False
Exit Sub
End If
Dim Cancel As Boolean
Cancel = BeforeCellChange(Target)
If Cancel Then
bitExit = True
Target = ""
End If
End Sub
Private Function BeforeCellChange(ByVal Target As Range) As Boolean
BeforeCellChange = True
End Function
```

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am sorry. I am sorry. What does x-y mean?   I want to have a correct validation in vba.

Comment: I think you want Data Validation.  You create the rules in the data validation settings of the cell.  Then Excel does the checks before allowing the change to be made.

Comment: Is there a way in VBA? Because I don't want to use {Data Tab} > Data Validation

Comment: No, you can capture the change After or you can capture the selection change.  But you cannot capture before the change is committed.  You can set the data validation through vba, but again that is before the user uses the cell not during.

Comment: You could possible use [Application.Undo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.Undo) if the entered value was invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It was really appropriate

Comment: A little patience is always the best answer. Thank you all .

Comment: Someone take me out of the limit. Where should I say this? Introduce a link to remove the restriction. I can't ask.

Comment: Someone take me out of the limit. Where should I say this? Introduce a link to remove the restriction. I can't ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

methods:

**[Offset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dzh-TW%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144169)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)** for restoring active cell's position

**[EnableEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents)**  for resetting target cell's value

```vb
Dim bitExit As Boolean
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = ActiveCell
    If bitExit Then
        'ActiveCell.Offset(-1).Select
        c.Offset(Target.Row - c.Row, Target.Column - c.Column).Select
        bitExit = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim Cancel As Boolean
    Cancel = BeforeCellChange(Target)
    If Cancel Then
        bitExit = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target = ""
        c.Offset(Target.Row - c.Row, Target.Column - c.Column).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Function BeforeCellChange(ByVal Target As Range) As Boolean
    rem set your rule
    If Target.Value <> "w" Then BeforeCellChange = True
End Function
```

Comment: @MansourDalir You can fix it to what your need any time. If you work it out all set , then edit my code here ok? Thanks.

Comment: Someone take me out of the limit. Where should I say this? Introduce a link to remove the restriction. I can't ask.

Comment: @MansourDalir I don't know. plz, visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=Restrictions+on+Asking+Questions).